# OData embedded entity and links

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using ASP.NET Web API with OData.

The scenario for this question is regarding the endpoints of 2 resources Company and CompanyInfo.

I would like to nest CompanyInfo class inside Company as a property. 
Now, how should I go about writing the CRUD in a Web API compliant way.

1. What is the correct methodology for embedding and retrieving resources as links?
2. What operations can be done on this embedded entity?

Comment: This is a very open ended question.  Stack overflow is a programming site.  If you have code of something you've implemented and are having problems with it, you'd get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following link for get inside Resource.
ex. `/oData/Company(123)/CompanyInfo`,and it support CURD when you use oData.